# Browsers, HTTP, HTTPS and redirection

Tags: security, http, redirect, browser, https

How firefox prevent redirect from HTTP to HTTPS by JS ?

I have this scenarios:

1. Parent: HTTPS + IFRAME HTTPS => iframe redirect by JS to HTTPS ok
2. Parent: HTTPS + IFRAME HTTPS => iframe redirect by JS to HTTP error
3. Parent: HTTPS + IFRAME HTTPS => iframe redirect by JS to HTTPS then redirect by Location Header immediately to HTTP => works on firefox, not work on chome, half work on IE (can see text but not css / js ... )

Could anybody help me to understand case 3?

Many thanks

Comment: Redirect from? HTTP? HTTPS? Same domain?

Comment: All From HTTPS and same domain. :)